# Using grep or awk, how can I count the number of characters in every line but also ignore certain lines based on their first character?

Tags: linux, awk, grep

Very simply, I have this kind of text in a file:

```
#number
3222
#number
3311
```

I'm using:

> awk '{print length}' file.txt

and it prints out:

> 7
>
> 4
>
> 7
>
> 4

But I just want it to print the length of the numbers and ignore the lines starting by "#", as to print:

> 4
>
> 4

Comment: You can do something like this `grep -v '#' file | awk '{print length}'`. Hope it helps. Welcome to U&L!

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Note that that `grep` would remove lines where `#` occurred _anywhere_.

Comment: @they I guess that author of the question specified  strict format of the file. I'v seen you answer. And it's look very nice! I'll look at `awk` syntax later.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Well, since they seem happy with your comment, you may want to convent it into a full-blown answer, so that they can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Tell `awk` to only print the length on lines where the first character is not a `#`:

```bsh
awk '!/^#/ { print length }' file
```

The `!/^#/` before the block is a regular expression matching test.  If the pattern `^#` matches, the following associated block is *not* considered (due to inverting the sense of the match with `!`).

The pattern `^#` tries to match a `#` at the very start of the current line.

Alternatively, if you want to output the length of lines that only contains digits:

```bsh
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { print length }' file
```

The pattern `^[[:digit:]]+$` matches only on lines consisting of a single consecutive run of digits, due to the anchoring with `^` at the start and `$` at the end.  You could also have used `!/[^[:digit:]]/` to avoid lines that contains any non-digit character.

Or, to only output the length of lines occurring straight after lines that are exactly `#number`:

```bsh
awk '$0 == "#number" { getline; print length }' file
```

Here, we do a string comparison with the current line, and if it is *exactly* `#number` (as in the example data in the question), we read the next line with `getline` and output its length.

Comment: That last one can just be `awk '$0=="#number"{f=1; next} f{print length; f=0}`, no getline with it's associated caveats/gotchas required (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).